# AffineTransform in gtk

Tags: gtk, cairo, affinetransform

I need to undergo some affinetransformation operation using gtk framework.

i found cairo but that does not solve my requirements. i need to crate transformation object and undergo some operations as under:

1. [tranform1 translateXBy:2.5 yBy:3.8];
2. [transform1 rotateByDegrees:23.0];
3. [transform1 appendTransform:transform2];

where transform1, transform2 are objects of AffineTransformation.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using PangoMatrix, the link is as under:

http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/pango/pango-Glyph-Storage.html#PangoMatrix